# Make the content of the column align left in vue datatable

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, tailwind-css

I have a datatable in my vue component.

Following is my header array.

```
HeaderArray() {
            return [
                {text: 'Document', value: 'document',classList: 'w-1/3'},
                {text: 'Added by', value: 'added_user_name',classList: 'w-1/3'},
                {text: 'Expiration', value: 'valid_date'},
                {text: 'Validity', value: 'validity_status',classList: 'w-1/3', align:'start'},
                {text: '', value: 'actions'},
            ];
        },
```

Cell content of the Validity column is centered, But I want them to be align left.

Eventhough I tried`align:'start'` the content display center...

How to make them align left?

Column header is aligned to left though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default column data in `vue-data-table` is left aligned. Hence, all the columns are already left aligned but if you want to make other columns are center aligned and `validity` as left aligned then you have to apply `align: 'center'` property in all the other column headers object instead of changing for `validity` column.

**Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
                {text: 'Document', value: 'document',classList: 'w-1/3', align:'center'},
                {text: 'Added by', value: 'added_user_name',classList: 'w-1/3', align:'center'},
                {text: 'Expiration', value: 'valid_date', align:'center'},
                {text: 'Validity', value: 'validity_status',classList: 'w-1/3'},
                {text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', align:'center'},
            ],
      documentDetails: [
        {
          document: 'Document 1',
          added_user_name: 'user 1',
          valid_date: '04-12-2022',
          validity_status: 'valid',
          actions: 'Edit'
        },
        {
          document: 'Document 2',
          added_user_name: 'user 2',
          valid_date: '05-12-2022',
          validity_status: 'invalid',
          actions: 'Edit'
        }
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="documentDetails"
      class="elevation-1"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```